# Can I create LinkedHashMap in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want add key value pair list in Map and insertion order should be mentioned of that list. So this thing can be done by using LinkedHashMap but I want this implementation in JavaScript. Is javascript support for LinkedHashMap? Can we use LinkedHashMap in javaScript?

Comment: Well...you could always write your own implementation, using the Java source for `LinkedHashMap` as a reference.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25041814/how-to-preserve-order-of-hashmap-in-javascript : may be this helps. It is for ES6 standard

Comment: https://github.com/kennyki/linked-hash-map/blob/master/src/linked-hash-map.js

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The new `Map` object can do this for you. [It will remember the original insertion order of the keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Example:

```js
let contacts = new Map()
contacts.set('Jessie', {phone: "213-555-1234", address: "123 N 1st Ave"})
contacts.has('Jessie') // true
contacts.get('Hilary') // undefined
contacts.set('Hilary', {phone: "617-555-4321", address: "321 S 2nd St"})
contacts.get('Jessie') // {phone: "213-555-1234", address: "123 N 1st Ave"}
contacts.delete('Raymond') // false
contacts.delete('Jessie') // true

for (let [key, value] of contacts) {
  console.log(key + ' = ' + value.phone + ' ' + value.address)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need. Map items are *already* guaranteed to iterated by insertion order.

See [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

> The keys in Map are ordered. Thus, **when iterating over it, a Map object returns keys in order of insertion.**

There are similar guarantees for normal objects:

> *Since ECMAScript 2015*, objects do preserve creation order for string and Symbol keys [.. and] iterating over an object with only string keys will yield the keys in order of insertion.

The internal implementations use a supplementary “linked list” to obtain this behavior even though it is not part of the names.